# mysql php, connecting to localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I paid someone to develop a website for me. It has been about a week and the website has stopped working. I am trying to get in working on localhost but am confused as to what I should be doing.

I created a database on phpmyadmin called called mike but when I go to check if it works i get the error Access denied for user

```
define ("DB_HOST", "host.mywebistehub.com"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "mike"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","aB1287z600!"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","mike"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)
or die("Couldn't make  connection."); //this is line 17
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link)
or die("Couldn't select database");
```

Comment: I might make a remote request from my machine to find out (nice password).

Comment: Posting database login information on a public forum is generally a bad idea.  Hopefully that really *isn't* a valid login.

Comment: You should use mysqli. Learn Object Oriented. But, it has to do with configuring `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`, which should be in your sever folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems clear enough.

The username "mike" isn't allowed to access the database using the password you've given from the hostname of the machine you are running your code on.

You need to find out which of those three things are wrong and either change the permissions on your database or the credentials you are trying to connect with.

---

> I am trying to get in working on localhost

```
define ("DB_HOST", "host.mywebistehub.com"); // set database host
```

`host.mywebistehub.com` is not `localhost`

Comment: when i set the password to "YES" it says a passport needs to be 41 digit number.

Comment: YES means "Yes, you are using a password" not "The password you are using is the word 'YES'".